# How do I save a project to a specific directory in Visual Basic 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express to create a project and in the near future a solution. But it creates the files in the wrong place. I can't see a Save As button for Projects or Solutions on the menu or the toolbar.

Does anyone know how to get it to save all the things it is supposed to save, where they are wanted, rather than where it feels like saving them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the files saved where I wanted by saving them where Visual Studio wanted to save them, and then copying the files to where I wanted to save them, and editing the resulting solution and project files to include the correct pathnames.

I can't believe this is what the designers intended, although I may be mistaken on that point.

Comment: Yes, the "Save as" only saves the current file, not the project.  Since all the files only save relative paths, you can move the folder where ever you want, which is typical in a development environment, where source control != development environment.